# Injecting classes with generic type parameters with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection

How do we inject classes with generic type parameters with dependency injection?

For example, here is my code. Obviously, this won't compile - TOject must be replaced with concrete type on line 2 and 3 of Main(), but that defeats the whole purpose because I want the concrete TObject to depend on something that is determined during runtime and to make sure that the type of the *processor* (that's been instantiated via Activator) is, exactly the same as that which the CreateNew method is expecting. Is there a way to make it work?

```
void Main() {
  //Get concrete type for TObject here
  // TObject = something;
  Type type = Type.GetType("Namespace.SomeType,SomeAssembly");
  IProcessor<TObject> processor = (IProcessor<TObject>)Activator.CreateNew(type);
  var proc = ProcessorFactory.CreateNew<TObject>(processor);
}

class ProcessorFactory {
  CreateNew<TObject>(IProcessor<TObject> processor)
}

class ExceptionProcessor : IProcessor<Exception> {
  public event EventHandler<Exception> event;

  public void DoSomething() {
    event.Invoke(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("text"));
  }
}

interface IProcessor<TObject> {
  event EventHandler<TObject> event;
  void DoSomething();
}
```

This is just a sample code that makes little sense in this form because it's simplified, but why I need something like is, is because the Processor in essense should be able to work with an object of any type. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: I´ll guess you´ll need some reflection to get this to work. Basically you can´t expect the compiler to guess your types that your program knows at runtime only, so you cannot cast your returned instanced to any generic type. You should use some combination of MakeGenericType and MakeGenericMethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of accomplishing this:

```
var processor = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var objectType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
var methodInfo = typeof(ProcessorFactory).GetMethod("CreateNew");
var generic =  methodInfo.MakeGeneric(new []{objectType});
var instance = generic.Invoke(factoryinstance,new []{processor});
```

Note that when mixing reflection and generics, you can't really use generic type parameters, but instead use some kind of inference, where you obtain the generic type according to some other mechanism and then use that type instance along the way. One way of doing this is exploring the type's generic parameters, as shown above.

Please do mind this code assumes a lot and is purposely kept simple so that the point is clearly illustrated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. However, do you think this is a better way than getting rid of generics and operating with "object" type and casting it to the required type (for example, the event handler that is assigned to Processor's event then has to cast event arguments to a certain type). I am thinking this is still better way because it preserves type safety within those instantiated classes, but I wonder what is considered a better pattern.

Comment: I don't think you should get rid of generics.. @user5080246. Also, once this works for you, please do mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: @user5080246 As I already mentioned in my comment to your question the compiler cannot (statically) infer any type-information which you provide at runtime. So you are stuck "operating with object" in any way. Only thing you can do is implement some kind of an interface that all your possible types implement and return an `IProcessor<MyInterface>`.